# Write Client.java code for Axis2 generated code from wsdl

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, wsdl, apache-axis

I am new with the Axis2 wsdl client generation.
I was able to generate the stub (ConfigurationServiceStub) and callback using the axis2, eclipse and tomcat.
How can I generate or what code should I write for the client. Java to make soap request.

The request is as follows:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:con="http://schema.unitedtote.com/ToteLink/2008/06/Configuration" xmlns:com="http://schema.unitedtote.com/ToteLink/2008/06/Common">
<soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <con:GetConfiguration>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <con:ConfigurationRequest>
        <com:Source>
           <com:SystemId>ABCD</com:SystemId>
           <com:SourceId>EFG</com:SourceId>
        </com:Source>
     </con:ConfigurationRequest>
  </con:GetConfiguration>
```

and the java code is as follows:

```
=== from Junit tester following code was generated:
/**
* Auto generated test method
*/
public  void testStartgetConfiguration() throws java.lang.Exception{
com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub stub = new com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub();
com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub.GetConfiguration getConfiguration8=(com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub.GetConfiguration)getTestObject(com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub.GetConfiguration.class);
// TODO : Fill in the getConfiguration8 here
stub.startgetConfiguration(
getConfiguration8,
new tempCallbackN65548()
);

public  void testgetConfiguration() throws java.lang.Exception{
com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub stub =
new com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub();//the default implementation should point to the right endpoint
com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub.GetConfiguration getConfiguration8=


(com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub.GetConfiguration)getTestObject(com.unitedtote.configuration.ConfigurationServiceStub.GetConfiguration.class);
    // TODO : Fill in the getConfiguration8 here
    assertNotNull(stub.getConfiguration(
    getConfiguration8));
        }
```

Comment: what should I do to create and send the SOAP Message? I want to test client adding the system Id and sourceID in it.. I really cant understand where and how I should add these parameters??

Comment: You have to fill the getConfiguration8 object with request data and then invoce the stub.getConfiguration() method. Message creation is internally handled by the stub, you don't have to worry about it.

Comment: Hi, I was trying to do some thing like :    getConfiguration8.getConfigurationRequest().getSource().setSourceId("EFG"); but it returns NULLPOINTERException . can you please elaborate a bit more? how to do it?

Comment: you're probably missing getConfiguration8 = new GetConfiguration() or something similar